# Highcharts wordcloud: Group words in sections and show words having maximum weight in each category with relative font sizes

Tags: css, highcharts, word-cloud

[Wordcloud showing words grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2OGV.png)

The image shows words grouped in 3 categories: Barack Obama, George Bush and Ronald Reagan. Each of this categories have a word with maximum frequency – I (70%), will (49%) and will (65%) respectively. Thus the font sizes of maximum frequency words are shown relatively.
Reference link for the image above - https://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Tag_Cloud/State_of_the_Union_Address_Most_Used_Words.php

I thought that one of the way to achieve this in Highcharts wordcloud is to plot 3 wordcloud charts in 3 containers. But all the maximum frequency words will be shown with same font size.

So is there any way to achieve the result like the attached image using Highcharts wordcloud?

Comment: Well, we can render three wordclouds in a one chart: http://jsfiddle.net/znm6f89r/8/ - but still, word weight is based on the size within the series. Maybe custom placement strategy is a way to go: http://jsfiddle.net/znm6f89r/28/ - but labels may not be within the column..

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus, your comment helped in understanding the concept of Wordcloud - words grouping. I have tried one example to achieve categorisation JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/znm6f89r/72/

Comment: I suggest to create an idea on Highcharts' [UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api) - I think this is cool feature and should be implemented in the core :)

Comment: @PawełFus Idea added on UserVoice. https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/33843778-highcharts-wordcloud-group-words-in-sections-and